# TweepyでTwitterアカウント毎に異なるVPNサーバーを適用したい

Tags: python, twitter, vpn

Twitterを複数のアカウントで運用しています。
アカウントの凍結を避けるため、VPNサーバーを通して、Tweepyにてつぶやき等を行いたいですが、その方法が分からずにおり、困っています。

CyberghostというVPNを活用しており、ProxyのIPアドレスはわかりますが、PortやUser、Passなど何を当てはめたらよいでしょうか？
サーバーに関しては無知です、ご教示お願いします。

```
import os

proxy = 'http://<user>:<pass>@<proxy>:<port>'

os.environ['http_proxy'] = proxy 
os.environ['HTTP_PROXY'] = proxy
os.environ['https_proxy'] = proxy
os.environ['HTTPS_PROXY'] = proxy
```

Comment: 参考: 英語版での関連質問 - [How to connect to a VPN/Proxy server via Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40708834)

Comment: @cubick 氏が参考質問としてコメントした通り、質問の本質はTweepy・Twitter本体よりもPythonでVPNを経由して通信することのようです。そして、そちらの回答を参照すると、Pythonでそれを行なうのは難しいようです。